# Carregar PHP dentro de JS é uma boa prática?

Tags: php, javascript, estilo-de-codificação

Vejo com bastante frequência em algumas perguntas aqui do SOpt alguns códigos que possuem variáveis PHP dentro de *scripts* em JS.

Vamos supor que o arquivo abaixo seja `index.php`.

```
<?php
     $var = "Me mostre";
?>

<script>
   function mostrarPalavra(){
      console.log(<?=$var?>);
   }
</script>
```

Isso é básico. Mas tem uma pergunta recente que o usuário está tentando montar um gráfico em JS usando o PHP para trazer da base de dados as informações. Sugeri a ele para fazer com AJAX e fazer tudo no JS.

Desenvolvedores e programadores:

**Isso é uma boa prática? Ou o mais correto é evitar essas situações?**

OBS: Me lembro que quando estava começando nessa área, quando queria resolver algumas coisas em um sistema fazia isso... de colocar PHP dentro de JS.

Pra mim isso não passa de RTA.

As linguagens dão suporte para fazer algo sem ter que fazer esse Mix.

Embora tenho me referido especificamente a PHP e JS, pode ser quaisquer outras linguagens.

Comment: De imediato a legibilidade do código (principalmente do PHP) fica prejudicada.

Comment: O que é RTA????

Comment: **Recurso Técnico Alternativo**, vulgo **Gambiarra**. Exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109680/grafico-em-barras-char-js

Comment: As perguntas onde você ve isso são fechada? rs

Comment: Rsrs não sei se entendi seu pensamento, mas geralmente não são fechadas.

Comment: Pra mim a gambiarra mais feia aí é usar tag script dentro do PHP com console.log.

Comment: Qual a alternativa @Bacco?

Comment: Esse exemplo não funcionou.

Comment: @durtto logar pelo próprio PHP, mostrar direto na tela pra quem tem um cookie de desenvolvedor, mostrar como comment de html, acessar uma página de fora pra registrar o erro, tem mil maneiras. depende do caso. Nem caberia no comment o tanto de alternativa que dá pra fazer. Geralmente chamar <script> de PHP já é um código que me cheira mal.

Comment: Quanto ao que foi perguntado, acho amplo demais, pq tem casos e casos. Por exemplo, se você está gerando um script de mapa JS usando o PHP para mesclar coordenadas, tá tudo certo. Dependendo do caso pode ser ótimo, dependendo do caso pode ser péssimo mesclar. Se a pessoa sabe o que tá fazendo, pode mesclar CSS, JS, SQL e HTML **tudo junto no mesmo** PHP que fica lindo. Se não sabe, fica nojento.

Comment: Entendi @Bacco. Li a opinião de todos, inclusive a resposta abaixo. Por mim pode fechar.

Comment: Parece ser duplicata sim. Na verdade queria saber se é correto mesmo. Eu vi que não tem nada de errado em fazer isso, porém, seria bom seguir o padrão da linguagem. Eu não faria isso mais.

Comment: @Zoom eu fechei, mas qq coisa deixe um comment aqui se precisar revisar algo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Definições iniciais

#### Boas práticas

Boas práticas são ruins. Fazer o certo para cada situação é o que deve ser feito.

Tem casos que uma opção é melhor que o outra, só analisando o caso concreto para dizer. Qualquer um que disser que é bom fazer isso ou aquilo sem olhar o caso concreto está especulando e até prestando um desserviço.

#### Gambiarra

Gambiarra é fazer o que vai contra o que os requisitos pedem. Claro que estamos falando de requisitos realistas e não inventados.

#### Qualquer linguagem

Se abrir para qualquer linguagem fica mais generalizado ainda. Fica mais difícil afirmar que um é melhor que outro. Obviamente que a solução de AJAX só funciona com JavaScript, e esse tipo de solução só é comum usando web.

Se for para usar essa técnica com SQL já há uma chance maior de ser válido.

Com HTML o padrão é fazer isso mesmo.

#### Separação de responsabilidades

De fato o ideal é que o JS seja mais puro, de preferência nem passar pela geração do PHP, ou seja, estar em arquivo separado e ser estático. É uma prática ruim misturar dados com código, JS é essencialmente código. Mas **só é ruim de fato se tiver outra forma melhor de fazer isto**. AJAX não é um solução universal. Só porque ela existe não quer dizer que deva ser usada sempre.

#### Exemplos do SOpt

É claro que as perguntas existentes no SOpt e outros sites normalmente não são boas referências de como não fazer algo. Há uma minoria de casos que podem ser usados como boa referência.

## É correto fazer isso?

**Se não dá problema algum fazer isto, é correto fazer**, desde que tenha uma justificativa para fazê-lo, o problema é fazer porque todo mundo está fazendo.

É problema pegar a receita de sobremesa cheia de açúcar e servir num encontro de diabéticos. Mas qual o problema de fazer sobremesas gostosas açucaradas num encontro de confeiteiros?

Tem que entender as motivações, tem que saber porque está fazendo aquilo. Aí tudo é válido e correto.

Colocar o resultado de um código em PHP como parte do que será inserido no código JS que será enviado ao navegador é absolutamente normal. Ele só não deve ser usado se não tiver sentido algum em fazer. Eu entendo que o exemplo da pergunta é só ilustrativo, mas é um caso onde não tem necessidade fazer isto.

#### JavaScript mal escrito

O maior problema do código da pergunta citada (nos comentários) não é o PHP, é o JS que não é parametrizado. Está usando o JS como gabarito de código e não como uma função normal. Se o JS for bem escrito e tiver uma função que recebe parâmetros, se enviar os dados pelo HTML e nele apenas chamar a função do JS, realmente é uma forma melhor. Isola o JS, o código, do HTML, os dados.

De fato o exemplo citado seria melhor escrito de outra forma.

#### AJAX

O AJAX é apenas uma solução para que o envio dos dados sejam feitos fora do HTML também. Realmente pode ser uma boa opção em alguns casos. Note que se o JS estiver certo, faz pouca diferença se os dados vieram pelo HTML ou por requisição AJAX. Se o AJAX não pode ou não deve ser usado no caso concreto, ele não é solução.

## Conclusão

No geral **eu não faria isto** na maioria das situações que eu encontrasse. Eu separaria bem o HTML do JS, mas jamais diria que está errado fazer em qualquer caso.

O Bacco deu um exemplo nos comentários. Eu acho que em vez de por no HTML algum dado pode colocar em um JS auxiliar e chamar o JS parametrizado. Digamos que isto seria um AJAX sem ser AJAX :) Ele pode ser útil para não poluir o HTML com dados que não sejam necessários nele. Mas note que ainda haverá uma separação clara de responsabilidades entre o que é dado posto em JS e o que é código.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).