# grafico com dados de um service REST

Tags: php, javascript, json, api, rest

Tenho um serviço REST feito em `PHP` e este me retorna dados em `JSON`.

Ao consumir a url da API em REST, preciso exibir os dados em gráficos feitos em javascript.

Alguém conhece algum framework em JS que gere gráficos de uma API REST e que seja free?

consigo fazer uma requisição em AJAX, como no exemplo abaixo, jogando a url do serviço e tratar os dados no gráfico.. como o exemplo acima.. baseado no [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109680/grafico-em-barras-char-js).. é possível?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //chama o ajax após a pagina ser carregada
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://servico/dados',
        success: function (dados) {
            //gera o grafico
            var options = {
                responsive:true
            };
            var ctx = document.getElementById("GraficoBarra").getContext("2d");
            var BarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(dados, options);
        }
    });
});
```

edit:

json

```
[{"GERENCIA":10,"EMPRESA":"1","FILIAL":"1"}]
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui pelo site, procurando por `grafico`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=grafico

Comment: eu entendo.. mas eu preciso de um que tenha suporte para consumir o serviço...

Comment: Se tens um JSON creio que qualquer um pode ser facilmente adaptado.

Comment: certo... dá uma olhada por favor no meu edit na pergunta.. é possivel?

Comment: Coloque um exemplo do formato do JSON de retorno do seu serviço.

Comment: ok... coloquei o exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não especificou nenhuma biblioteca, deixo um exemplo usando [Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/):

```js
var json = [{"GERENCIA":10,"EMPRESA":"1","FILIAL":"1"}];
json = json[0];//primeiro indice do JSON
var labels = [];//array com as labels
var dataChart = [];//para criar a série
for(i in json){//percorre o json e monta as labels e a série
 labels.push(i);
  dataChart.push(json[i]);
}
var data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Meus dados",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: dataChart,
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data:data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="250" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: que show!... vou testar

Comment: uma pergunta... estou trazendo meu json através do angular... como eu faria pra colocar o json que vem através do scope na variavel "json" que vc criou?

Comment: @novato Se entendi bem é só vc atribuir na variável `var json = $scope.json;`, seria isso?

Comment: ok... mas como seria se o json tivesse mais de uma linha?

Comment: ok... mas como seria isdso? jogo o script dentro da tag que tem o ng-Controller?

Comment: @novato Se tiver mais de um índice vc precisa percorrer todas criando outro for exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/mnf1rveq/.

Comment: @novato sim você pode colocar no controller, veja um exemplo aqui. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267438/chart-js-angular

Comment: massa... tem como eu escrever algum texto na barra do grafico? pequisei e é algo relacionado ao tooltip.. mas nao achei nada exato

Answer (score 0):

É muito simples, depois de vc recuperar os seus dados num JSON, pode enviar para javascript D3. POde ser usando AJAX ou não.

Aqui o link da biblioteca [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery).

### Nota, no D3 os códigos já estão prontos, basta copiar e colar. São gratuitos.

Exemplo:

1. Faça a sua consulta REST e recupere o resultado em JSON. Isso seu código já esta ok.
2. Aqui vc pode seguir 2 caminhos. Ou grava seu JSON como um arquivo separado para ser lido depois ou guarda seu JSON numa variável para ser lido no processo seguinte.
3. Cria o tipo de grafico desejado entre os muitos que existem no D3.js carregando a biblioteca d3.js e aponta para os seus dados. Seja no arquivo, seja na varável.

Assim:

```
//Digamaos que esse é seu JSON, bem simples
[
  {
  "name": "Top Level",
  "parent": "null",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Level 2: A",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Son of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Level 2: B",
      "parent": "Top Level"
    }
  ]
}
]

//Esse vai ser o seu arquivo html ou php com javascript
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Collapsible Tree Example</title>

    <style>

    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// load the external data=======>Aqui vc está carregando de um arquivo externo usando o método d3.json.
d3.json("treeData.json", function(error, treeData) {
  root = treeData[0];
  update(root);
});

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Declare the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

}

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Exemplo extraído da [página](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8329447)

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo de utilização da D3 neste caso?

Comment: exato.. pode informar um exemplo?